# HLK-RM04 wifi shield factory reset?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wifi

I have this HLK-RM04:

[image]

It came with  no catalogue or manual
all threads about it are in Chinese 
after when I found the configuration webpage and changing it to client 
it wont connect and it stopped board casting hlink wifi
how could i reset to factory settings?

After very long search I found an English manual.

[image]

What does Trst means ?
I don’t understand what I must do to reset it!

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has posted an answer, and I finally found one myself. Ground pin 10 for 6 seconds.